# actionscript to populate a list from sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, adobe, flash-builder

using Adobe Flash Builder 4.6

the below code is what I am using to try to get actionscript to populate a list a from sqlite table. It brings back the correct number of records but it shows the results as:
    [object Object]
    [object Object]
    [object Object]

Can someone tell me what I may be doing wrong?

```
                    private var strGetDBName:String = "CPRInstr.db";
        private var strGetCurrentTableName:String = "lkStates";

        import flash.data.SQLConnection;
        import flash.data.SQLResult;
        import flash.data.SQLStatement;
        import flash.filesystem.File;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        private var conn:SQLConnection;

        private function init():void
        {
            conn = new SQLConnection();
            conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openSuccess);
            //conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, openFailure);
            var dbFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(strGetDBName);
            conn.openAsync(dbFile);
        }

        private function openSuccess(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            conn.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openSuccess);
            //conn.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, openFailure);
            getData();
        }

        private function getData():void
        {
            var select:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            select.sqlConnection = conn;
            //select.text = "SELECT id, txtState, txtAbbrev FROM " + strGetCurrentTableName;
            select.text = "SELECT id, txtState FROM lkStates";
            select.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
            //select.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);
            select.execute();
        }

        private function selectResult(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            var result:SQLResult = null;
            result = event.currentTarget.getResult(); 

            if(result.data)
            {
                list.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(result.data);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I tried to match your variables for example.

```
var result:SQLResult = select.getResult();
list.dataProvider = new DataProvider(result.data);

if(result.data)
{
   for(var i:int = 0; i < result.data.length; i++)
    {
      var tState:Object = result.data[i];
      trace("var1 "+tState.var1+"var2 "+tState.var2...etc)
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean within the function `selectResult()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set labelField to your list to a field name in your table so that it can appear in the list. In the declaration of your list type : labelField = "txtState" and you will get the information from this field.